# Store Numpy as pickled Pandas, Pickled Numpy or HDF5

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, format

I right now working with 300 float features coming from a preprocessing of item information. Such items are identified by  a UUID (i.e. a string). The current file size is around 200MB.  So far I have stored them as Pickled `numpy`arrays. Sometimes I need to map the UUID for an item to a Numpy row. For that I am using a dictionary (stored as json) that maps UUID to row in a `numpy` array.

I was tempted to use Pandas and replace that dictionary for a Pandas index. I also discovered the HF5 file format but I would like to know a bit more when to use each of them.

I use part of the array to feed a `scikit-Learn` based algorithm and then to perform classification on the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Storing pickled numpy arrays is indeed not an optimal approach. Instead, you can use,

- `numpy.savez` to save a dictionary of numpy array in a binary format
- store pandas DataFrame in HDF5
- directly use [PyTables](https://pytables.github.io/) to write your numpy arrays to HDF5.

HDF5 is a preferred format to store scientific data that includes, among others,

- parallel read/write capabilities
- on the fly compression algorithms
- efficient querying
- ability to work with large datasets that don't fit in the RAM.

Although, the choice of the output file format to store a small dataset of 200MB is not that critical and is more a matter of convenience.

Comment: Also worth mentioning [`h5py`](http://www.h5py.org), which is somewhat nicer than PyTables for storing purely array-like data.